A regex to test whether an input contains two specified strings and the part between them does not contain any element of the set of specified strings
Given two strings (denoted by A and B) and a set N of strings, I need to write a regular expression to test whether a given input string W contains a substring S, where S is any substring that satisfies all of the following three conditions: 1. starts with A; 2. ends with B; 3. any element of N does not occur in the part between A and B (this part does not overlap with A and B).
For example, I chose "ab" as A, "bc" as B, ["a", "cb", "cd"] as N. If "ec" is the inner part, then "abecbc" is the string that satisfies all of the three conditions: if W contains such a substring, the regex must return true. My first variant is the following regex:
var T = /(?=ab.*bc)(?=(?!ab.*a.*bc))(?=(?!ab.*cb.*bc))(?=(?!ab.*cd.*bc))/;  

I chose W = S = "abecbc". This regex works as expected:
T.test("abecbc");
// true

But I am interested in the following problem: how to write a functionally equivalent regex without using the positive lookahead (?=) as the AND operator?
So my second variant is the following:
var R = /ab(?!.*?(?:a|cb|cd).*)bc/;

But R.test("abecbc") evaluates to false. So let us split R into three parts:
/ab(.*)/.test("abecbc")

returns true. Then
/(.*)bc/.test("abecbc")

returns true.
The inner part (i.e. the part between "ab" and "bc") is "ec". And
/(?!.*?(?:a|cb|cd).*)/.test("ec")

returns true, which is expected. So there must be three truths, and there are no more parts in R. Then why does
/ab(?!.*?(?:a|cb|cd).*)bc/.test("abecbc")

evaluate to false? And how to write a correct regex that solves the problem described in the first paragraph of the post without using the positive lookahead (?=) as the AND operator?
EDIT
My question is not a duplicate of this question: I need an explanation of why the particular regex (R) returns false instead of true. Another difference is that I do not need to test whether the inner part contains a specified string.

https://regex101.com/r/AJzqWp/1

@WiktorStribiżew: there is no need to test for ec in the middle. And in your regex I do not understand the purpose of b?.

What is the explanation of why R returns false?

If you do not need to test for ec inside, it is even simpler, ab(?!(?:a|cb|cd|ab|bc).)*bc. You need to include start and end delimiters into the lookahead. Still a duplicate, you just need a tempered greedy token

@WiktorStribiżew Aside from the missing outer group in your regex, using a tempered greedy token would result in false negatives when what's between A and B matches one of N by overlapping with B, violating the OP's rule of "this part does not overlap with A and B". For example, abcbc should match because c is not any of a, cb and cd, but with your approach it would not match because cb overlaps with bc. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/NqLbfV/5

@blhsing There is no need in any outer group here. And your regex in the answer yields the same three matches as the ab(?:(?!a|cb|cd|ab|bc).)*bc regex.

@WiktorStribiżew Oops I posted the wrong demo. By missing an outer group I was referring to the regex ab(?!(?:a|cb|cd|ab|bc).)*bc that you posted, which you have now fixed by properly making the non-capturing group the outer group. Demo of the said false negative with your regex: https://regex101.com/r/M3EgpH/1 And demo of matching the same input with my regex: https://regex101.com/r/M3EgpH/2

I do not understand the role of |ab|bc in ab(?:(?!a|cb|cd|ab|bc).)*bc.

@lyricallywicked The inclusion of |ab|bc in the negative lookahead prevents A and B from occurring between A and B . It's another way of performing a non-greedy match.

@blhsing: But I have not mentioned that I need a non-greedy match: actually, greedy match would be preferable. And "0abbc1ab2bc3ababc4abcbbc5ab6bc7".match(/ab(?:(?!a|cb|cd).)*bc/g) gives the same three matches, so this regex seems to solve the problem too?

@lyricallywicked Right, but again not if you want to uphold your rule of "this part does not overlap with A and B". Demo of your greedy regex not matching my sample input of abcbc: https://regex101.com/r/M3EgpH/3

@blhsing has answered your question in the first paragraph of his/her answer. Your suggestion of attempting to match ab(?:(?!a|cb|cd).)*bc seems to be the most direct solution. Demo. As I expect you know, (?:(?!a|cb|cd).)* is called a tempered greedy token solution.

@WiktorStribiżew: <it is even simpler, ab(?!(?:a|cb|cd|ab|bc).)*bc. <...> regex in the answer yields the same three matches as the ab(?:(?!a|cb|cd|ab|bc).)*bc regex> — the "abcbc" string satisfies all of the three conditions ("ab" as A, "bc" as B, ["a", "cb", "cd"] as N), but both /ab(?!(?:a|cb|cd|ab|bc).)*bc/.test("abcbc") and /ab(?:(?!a|cb|cd|ab|bc).)*bc/.test("abcbc") return false. So these two regexes cannot be considered as options for a solution.

@CarySwoveland: <ab(?:(?!a|cb|cd).)*bc seems to be the most direct solution> — no, it is not a solution: the "abcbc" string satisfies all of the three conditions ("ab" as A, "bc" as B, ["a", "cb", "cd"] as N), but /ab(?:(?!a|cb|cd).)*bc/.test("abcbc") returns false.

@blhsing:  — what fixed regex were you referring to?

@lyricallywicked I was referring to the typo Wiktor made in ab(?!(?:a|cb|cd|ab|bc).)*bc, where the non-capture group is supposed to be outside the negative lookahead assertion. Wiktor later corrected it to ab(?:(?!a|cb|cd|ab|bc).)*bc.

Your attempted regex of R = /ab(?!.*?(?:a|cb|cd).*)bc/ fails to match abecbc because a negative lookahead pattern is a zero-width assertion, so with your regex bc has to immediately follow ab. And if you try fixing it by adding .* before bc then there's no guarantee that a match of a|cb|cd occurs between ab and bc.
You can instead capture B and what comes after it so that you can use the capture as an ending in a negative lookahead assertion to avoid a match when there's any of N between A and B:
ab(?=.*?(bc.*))(?!.*(?:a|cb|cd).*\1).*?bc

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/NqLbfV/4
EDIT: The solution above performs a non-greedy match, but since you later indicated in the comments that you desire a greedy match, you can instead capture what comes before A and use a negative lookbehind assertion to avoid an occurrence of any of N between A and B:
(?<=(.*))ab.*(?<!\1ab.*(?:a|cb|cd).*)bc

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/7xuUNP/2
Note that this requires that your browser supports variable-width lookbehind patterns, which is currently the case for all major modern browsers.

How to write a regex R such that, for example, "0abbc1ab2bc3ababc4abcbbc5ab6bc7".match(R) will return ["abbc", "ab2bc", "ab6bc"]? I used the variant in the answer as /(ab(?=.*(bc.*))(?!.*(?:a|cb|cd).*\1))/g, but it returns [ "ab" ].

You can just include .*?bc in the pattern. I've updated the answer accordingly then.

If it is possible, please add a more detailed explanation of R: I do not understand why it “essentially matches only abcd as long as there isn't any of a, cb and cd after ab”.

I've rephrased my explanations then. Hopefully it's now clearer.

[1/2]> Yes, thank you for the explanation. There is a very desirable additional property for a regex, but I forgot to mention it in the original post. I need the regex to be greedy in both directions. In other words, I need the regex to be able to extract all longest matching substrings (from left to right). Suppose that W = "0ababbc1ab2bc3abaabc4abcbbc5ab6bcbcbc7". I chose "ab" as A, "bc" as B, ["aa", "cb", "cd"] as N. If X is greedy in both directions, the expected output of W.match(X) is [ "ababbc1ab2bc", "abc4abc", "ab6bcbc" ]. <[1/2]

[2/2]> Let M denote the regex constructed by the logic of the regex in your current answer: M = /ab(?=.*?(bc.*))(?!.*(?:aa|cb|cd).*\1).*?bc/g. The output of W.match(M) is different from the expected one: [ "ababbc", "ab2bc", "abc4abc", "ab6bc" ]. Can you edit your answer to suggest possible options for X or should I ask a separate question (I do not even know whether such two-way greedy regex exists)? <[2/2]

I've updated my answer accordingly then.
